# Android - retrieve images and data from database server

Tags: android, android-image

I'm facing problem in retrieving data and images from the remote database server. I tried to search from Internet for few days, but still could not found a useful link, tutorial or solution that can help me to solve my problem. Anyone here could please help me. You may provide me a link that showing detailed tutorial. I'm new to Android. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I saved my image url on the database, i wish to retrieve the url and show it on my android as images. Please, any help could save my life.

Thank you in advance.

==================================================
I found my problem. I just remove  from my manifest file, then the program is working. It is strange, but I also don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I solved my problem by just removing the 
           "uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" "
 from manifest file.

Hope this can help others :) good luck

Comment: Is <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> set in the manifest?

Comment: yes, already set the internet permission. i think it is sdk version problem. :)